# Angular ng-table server-side pagination

Tags: angularjs, pagination, ngtable

I have a problem with server side pagination. I am loading paged data from server. The data loads correct, however the display of the data is strange:
e.g. when I move from page 1 to page 2, I can see the data from page one on the bottom of the list for a brief moment, then it disappears. In the example there is no such behavior, and I cannot find what is wrong with my code.
SO here is my Controller:

```
angular.module('ttUserList').controller('UserListController', userListController);

userListController.$inject = ['ngTableParams', 'UserList'];

function userListController(ngTableParams, UserList) {
    var vm = this;
    var USERS_PER_PAGE = 10;

    vm.tableParams;
    vm.getData = getData;
    activate();

    function activate() {
        vm.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
            page: 1,
            count: USERS_PER_PAGE,
            sorting: {
                name: 'asc' //initial sorting
            }
        }, {
            total: 0,
            getData: getData
        })
    }

    function getData($defer, params) {
        UserList.getUsersPage(params.url()).then(function (users) {
            params.total(users.total);
            $defer.resolve(users.list);
        });
    }
}
```

Html is very simple:

```
<table data-ng-table="userList.tableParams"  data-show-filter="true" class="bordered responsive-table hoverable">
    <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="user in $data">
            <td data-title="'Name'" data-sortable="'name'"
                filter="{ 'name,surname': 'text' }">{{user.name}} {{user.surname}}</td>
            <td data-title="'Login'" data-sortable="'login'"
                filter="{ 'login': 'text' }">{{user.login}}</td>
            <td data-title="'Location'" data-sortable="'location'"
                filter="{ 'location': 'text' }">{{user.location}}</td>
            <td data-title="'Details'">
                <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" data-ui-sref="users.details({id: user.id})" data-translate>DETAILS</md-button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The data that comes from the service is correct. Does anyone see any problem here?

Comment: Can you provide a working demo? If not - can you at leats post the service response?